# How to fake a touch event in the system

Tags: android

Is it possible to make a 'fake' touch event on android? (if necessary with root access)
The app would run in the background and let an other app think there was a 'real' touch event.

I want this for an app wich allows the iControlPad (bluetooth controller) to make a touch event by pressing a (hardware) button.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may run into a sandboxing issue. You can create a test project that instruments the project in question using TouchUtils but AFAIK that's all you can do.

Comment: You may want to look into how monkeyrunner works. Perhaps with root and some linux action you can produce the same effect from an app.